# Error came when try to upload a unmanaged package after clicking the "Upload" button. Any suggestions

Tags: upload, unmanaged-package

i got the error when i try to upload a unmanaged package in the final step of package creation process. this is happening in my free developer account.

the error screen shot is given below. any thoughts of why this issue coming now. a week ago i was able to create a package (un) without an issue. But this is new.

[image]

Comment: One way to check whats causing this issue is by adding compoenents one by one .I have observed that if one thats somehow unsupported can cause this kind of issue .Try removing some compoenets and see whats creeps this issue

Comment: It works now. the issue is one of classes throwing error when i compile all classes. Thanks.